Does a decomposition redox reaction with a single reactant and non-elemental products exist?

Does a decomposition redox reaction exist with a single reactant and non-elemental products and that this decomposition reaction cannot be decomposed in any condition to yield elemental products.

For example, the decomposition reaction $\ce{NH4NO3 -> N2O + 2H2O}$ would not qualify because as I stated, I want a decomposition redox reaction with a single reactant with non-elemental products, but this reaction in certain conditions, occurs as: $\ce{2NH4NO3 -> 2N2 + O2 + 4H2O}$. Thus, I have to reject this.
Please also note that the reaction which you provide contains only one single reactant and does not require the presence of any catalyst or anything else.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

OP asked the question in the title of the post:

Does a decomposition redox reaction with a single reactant and non-elemental products exist?

I think there are a lot of possibilities exists, most of which are discussed in comments' section. The one of most qualified reaction did not discussed among these comments is following:

The phosphorous acid $(\ce{H3PO3})$ decomposes into phosphoric acid $(\ce{H3PO4})$and phosphine $(\ce{PH3})$ when heated over $\pu{200 ^\circ C}$ (Wikipedia). The balanced equation for this reaction is:
$$\ce{4H3PO3 ->[\gt \pu{200 ^\circ C}] 3H3PO4 + PH3}$$
This reaction is well qualified satisfying all aspects of OP's request. It is a redox disproportionation reaction involving only one reactant and products are non-elemental, which cannot decompose further to elements.

Interestingly, in same Wikipedia article, there is non-redox reaction involving one reagent giving non-elemental products:

The thermal degradation of bicarbonate:
$$\ce{2HCO3- ->[heat] CO3- + H2CO3 -> CO3- + CO2 + H2O}$$

